# ffmpeg absolute path error

Tags: video, ffmpeg, path, subtitles

I've created a program that runs automatically an ffmpeg code line and it works with all functions except one:
if I try to overlay some subtitles there's a problem with the absolute path, if i use the same code in a shell opened on the desktop it works but if I write the absolute path it doesn't work.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "subtitles=subs.srt:force_style='OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=4,Outline=1,Shadow=0,MarginV=20,Fontsize=10,PrimaryColour=&H0000ff&'" output.mp4
```

If I change ffmpeg, input.mp4, subs.srt, output.mp4 with their own absolute path("c:\users\home\desktop\input.mp4") it doesn't work!

I tried also:

- "c:\users\home\desktop\input.mp4"
- "c:/users/home/desktop/input.mp4"
- 'c:\users\home\desktop\input.mp4'
- 'c:/users/home/desktop/input.mp4'

Error:

```
    [subtitles @ 0000000002ab79c0] Unable to parse option value "UsersFamigliaDesktop569.srt" as image size
    Last message repeated 1 times
[subtitles @ 0000000002ab79c0] Error setting option original_size to value UsersFamigliaDesktop569.srt.
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0000000002ab78e0] Error applying options to the filter.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002edcd20] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args 'C:UsersFamigliaDesktop569.srt:force_style=OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=4,Outline=1,Shadow=0,MarginV=20,Fontsize=15,PrimaryColour=&H000000&'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

What can I do?

strategaD

(I can't speek English very well, sorry)

Comment: Escape the : and \ by prepending with \ i.e. : -> \: and \ -> \\

Comment: Regular escapes don't apparently cut it with the subtitles filter.

Answer (score 8):

[According to this bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3334), the error you are seeing is an issue with the subtitles filter specifically.

On Windows, for the subtitles filter to work with absolute paths:

> "each special character needs to be escaped [...] and then each escape needs to be re-escaped".

What this effectively means is that you need `\\` before the colon `:` (i.e. `\\:`) and `\\\\` in place of single backslashes `\` e.g.:

```
subtitles=C\\:\\\\users\\\\\\\\home\\\\desktop\\\\subs.srt
```

To avoid issues, there should also be no spaces in your subtitles path (quotes do not matter one way or the other for paths without spaces and are thus not necessary).

If you miss a single slash (e.g. `\:` vs. `\\:` or `\\`,`\\\` vs. `\\\\`) or include spaces in the path, you will continue to  have issues.

*Note that this solution is only for the subtitles filter -- you can specify paths for your input and output files normally (e.g. `c:\users\home\desktop\input.mp4`).*

Also note that you only need quotes if the path contains spaces e.g.

```
c:\users\home\desktop\input.mp4   # no space in path
```

vs.

```
"c:\users\home\desk top\input.mp4"   # space in path ("desk top")
```

Finally, using your original command and `c:\users\home\desktop\` as an absolute path would yield:

```
ffmpeg -i c:\users\home\desktop\input.mp4 -filter_complex "subtitles=c\\:\\\\users\\\\home\\\\desktop\\\\subs.srt:force_style='OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=4,Outline=1,Shadow=0,MarginV=20,Fontsize=10,PrimaryColour=&H0000ff&'" c:\users\home\desktop\output.mp4
```

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it. =)